# Make Circle of a UIView which is of different width and height

Tags: ios, uiview, cornerradius

I've a `UIView` which is of different width and height that's {width:45,height:37}, when I tried to make it exact circle using `cornerRadius` of it's layer, the result was not an exact circle which I want. Is the different between width and height makes this difference? How to get exact circle with this size?

btw, here's my code -

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.frame.size.width/2.f;
myView.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I also tried, `myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.frame.size.width/myView.frame.size.height;`

It doesn't make the trick! My more research about this, if `myView` will be of same width and height then `myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.frame.size.width/2.f;` would work fine! But somehow I can't make it of same width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @sebastienFCT suggestions, I applied this logic to get (little closer) circle shape for `myView`.

```
CGFloat max = MAX(myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height);
CGFloat min = MIN(myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height);
CGFloat diff = max - min;
CGFloat borderWidth = max - (diff/2.f);
myView.frame = CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.origin.y, borderWidth, borderWidth);
myView.layer.cornerRadius = borderWidth/2.f;
myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I know it's not a proper way, but for now it helped me to send by first build to the client and made my boss happy!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it is the best answer, but I would try to `reframe` my view and then setup my `cornerRadius`:

```
CGFloat borderWidth = MAX(myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height);
myView.frame = CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.origin.y, borderWidth, borderWidth);
[myView.layer setCornerRadius:borderWidth/2];
```

By doing such thing, you could face issue with your interface (the `width` or the `height` of your view will be bigger and can hide over views) that's why I think there's probably a better practice.